# Powder room venting into ceiling space?

Tags: bathroom, vent

Is it OK to vent a powder room into the ceiling space?

Humidity isn't the issue just odour. I don't have access to the outside unfortunately. I see there are ductless fans for this purpose, but they have charcoal filters and I would rather like to avoid having to replace the filters.

Comment: I know it would not be up to code in my state. Where in the world do you live?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a half bath (no shower/bathtub), sure, that'd be fine. It's done all the time.

If there's moisture present, you may have to find another way. Recent code (recent in my time frame), technically speaking, forbids it. If you ceiling space is not a wide-open attic, you could make a mold trap by introducing moisture to a dark unvented environment.